# CHKDSK (check disk) for Android

Tags: internal-storage

My Android tablet "went berserk" this week and eventually, I managed to stop the behaviour that was stopping me from even getting the "desktop" to stay up front.

I eventually discovered a corrupted directory (the name was "mashed").  I deleted it and the device now seems stable.

What is the Android equivalent of the Windows/DOS `CHKDSK` command?  I want to be able to scan the device and repair any nascent problems on a regular basis.

Comment: note that you'll need root privilege to run fsck on system partitions.